# MFC Send the object in message

Tags: c++, mfc

Can i send the message with object? 
Something like:

```
myClass *myObj = new myClass();
pDlg->SendMessage(MyEvent, NULL, (LPARAM)&myObj); // Sends without any errors
...
afx_msg LRESULT MyApp::GetEvent(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    myClass *zxc = new myClass();
    zxc = lParam; // Something like this... but doesn't work
}
```

Comment: myClass *zxc = (myClass) lParam;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the pointer there-and-back as appropriate:

**Sender:**

```
pDlg->SendMessage(MyEvent, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&myObj));
```

**Receiver:**

```
afx_msg LRESULT MyApp::GetEvent(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    myClass * zxc = reinterpret_cast<myClass*>(lParam);
    // ...
}
```